# Question about the proof of Goldbach's weak conjecture

Tags: analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

H.A. Helfgott recently proved Goldbach's weak conjecture here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.2897v2.pdf

In (1.1), he explains that he is trying to show that $$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = N}\Lambda(n_1)\Lambda(n_2)\Lambda(n_3) > 0$$ if $N\ge7$, (N, 2) = 1. If the paper is correct, he successfully proved this. However, doesn't this shows that all integers are the sum of 3 prime powers, since the Von Mangoldt function at n is nonzero if n is a prime power? The most common generating functions that I have seen for the circle method have been of the form: $$F_N(\alpha) = \sum_{p\le N}\ln p e^{2\pi i\alpha p} $$ rather than $$F_n(\alpha) = \sum_{k\le N}\Lambda(k)e^{2\pi i \alpha k}$$

Comment: It is equivalent to that, since it is true if there exists prime powers $n_1,n_2,n_3$ such that $n_1+n_2+n_3=N$ and the converse is also true. To prove that one of those triplets is entirely composed of primes would be another story. I have not read the proof but I think that that would need to be explained later, or the author thought it was too obvious (for me it is not at all obvious, I don't even see a way)

Comment: But in many other papers that mention the circle method such as http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6656.pdf, the same thing is done, and no explanation is given.

Comment: Now that I read the relevant part of the paper, I see that his proof of *Corollary 1.1* (Weak Goldbach implies that every integer $>4$ is the sum of at most $4$ primes) is kind of inconsistent with him believing that it is so trivial to prove that the sum positivity implies Weak Goldbach that the proof shouldn't be included in the paper. Maybe it is some well known result, but I don't know.

Comment: I searched around and I think that Lemma 1 (or some refinements of it) of this article implies it: http://alexricemath.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Goldbach.pdf

Comment: On page 114 it is written: _"It only remains to show that the contribution of terms with $n_1$, $n_2$, or $n_3$ non-prime to the sum in (8.46) is negligible"_, and the proof is given right after this statement.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment:

On page 114 it is written: *"It only remains to show that the contribution of terms with $n_1$, $n_2$, or $n_3$ non-prime to the sum in (8.46) is negligible"*, and the proof is given right after this statement.

Comment: Later on, Helfgott expanded the paper into a book form, and this exact argument now appears on page 276 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.05438v2.pdf.